# С# datagridview calendar column строка не распознана как действительное значение

Tags: c#, дата

При выборе в таблице в колонке с датами, даты со значением после 2030 года возникает такая ошибка.

[image: ошибка]

код для колонки с датами взят с https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.110).aspx

он такой:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace tnp
{
    public class CalendarColumn : DataGridViewColumn
    {
        public CalendarColumn() : base(new CalendarCell())
        {
        }

        public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
        {
            get
            {
                return base.CellTemplate;
            }
            set
            {
                // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
                if (value != null &&
                    !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CalendarCell)))
                {
                    throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CalendarCell");
                }
                base.CellTemplate = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class CalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    {

        public CalendarCell()
            : base()
        {
            // Use the short date format.
            this.Style.Format = "d";
        }

        public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
            initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
            base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
                dataGridViewCellStyle);
            CalendarEditingControl ctl =
                DataGridView.EditingControl as CalendarEditingControl;
            // Use the default row value when Value property is null.
            if (this.Value == null||this.Value.ToString().Length==0)
            {
                ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.DefaultNewRowValue;
            }
            else
            {
                ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.Value;
            }
        }

        public override Type EditType
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the type of the editing control that CalendarCell uses.
                return typeof(CalendarEditingControl);
            }
        }

        public override Type ValueType
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains.

                return typeof(DateTime);
            }
        }

        public override object DefaultNewRowValue
        {
            get
            {
                // Use the current date and time as the default value.
                return DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }

    class CalendarEditingControl : DateTimePicker, IDataGridViewEditingControl
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView;
        private bool valueChanged = false;
        int rowIndex;

        public CalendarEditingControl()
        {
            this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue 
        // property.
        public object EditingControlFormattedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Value.ToShortDateString();
            }
            set
            {
                if (value is String)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // This will throw an exception of the string is 
                        // null, empty, or not in the format of a date.
                        this.Value = DateTime.Parse((String)value);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // In the case of an exception, just use the 
                        // default value so we're not left with a null
                        // value.
                        this.Value = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Implements the 
        // IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method.
        public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
            DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return EditingControlFormattedValue;
        }

        // Implements the 
        // IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method.
        public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
            DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
            this.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
            this.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex 
        // property.
        public int EditingControlRowIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return rowIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                rowIndex = value;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey 
        // method.
        public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
            Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
        {
            // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.
            switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Left:
                case Keys.Up:
                case Keys.Down:
                case Keys.Right:
                case Keys.Home:
                case Keys.End:
                case Keys.PageDown:
                case Keys.PageUp:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit 
        // method.
        public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
        {
            // No preparation needs to be done.
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property.
        public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .EditingControlDataGridView property.
        public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
        {
            get
            {
                return dataGridView;
            }
            set
            {
                dataGridView = value;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .EditingControlValueChanged property.
        public bool EditingControlValueChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return valueChanged;
            }
            set
            {
                valueChanged = value;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .EditingPanelCursor property.
        public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Cursor;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
        {
            // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell
            // have changed.
            valueChanged = true;
            this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
            base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
        }
    }
}
```

в чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: В региональных настройках Панели Управления можно задать параметр, как отображать год, заданный двумя цифрами. По умолчанию: с 1930 по 2029.

Comment: но я же не отображаю его как две цифры, и при том если я выбираю дату в простом дайтпикере, который находится не в гриде, то я могу выбирать дату из любого диапазона.

Comment: и где можно поменять это значение? я не могу найти что-то(

Comment: Опишите, как это используется. Чтобы можно было пощупать на практике. Я добавил этот код в проект, добавил в `DataGridView` колонку типа `CalendarColumn`. Работает. Даты можно вводить любые.

Comment: Вы были правы, что скорее всего проблема в том, что год показывается двумя цифрами, я как-то не заметил сразу, что при сворачивании дейтпикера дата становится такой: Ср 17.05.17 Правда в классе колонки ставится формат d - что указывает как я понимаю не на сокращенную форму года. Как можно убрать такой формат?